copy last row data with locked cells and paste in next row under
I have a spreadsheet that operates like a running log. I currently copy the last row data and past in the next row under. I then edit the row data for the new days information. there are equations in some of the cells that calculate numbers from other cells in the row and from cells in previous row.
I am trying to create a macro that will copy and paste the row data from the last row and paste under it in new row while locking the cells with equations in it.
I have been able to create a macro that unlocks the cells, copy and pastes the row data under the row and re-locks the cells. But it only selects the row number from when I made the macro. How do I get it to continually copy from the last row?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
